# How to track bacteria/ protozoa, unicellular algae in big volumes?

Tags: bacteriology, phycology

Is there any special cameras and dyes? If I want to track migration/motion of them in 0.1-0.5 cubic metres.

Comment: for 3d imaging, you can maybe use MRI and hyperspectral imageing mostly. MRI requires that you feed the bacteria with something radioactive and then have access to an MRI which costs about 100 euros or 300 euros if you are lucky. you'd be lucky if you could see bacteria in an MRI in water. for practical options, sounds like you should arrange a tank with a system of sampling, so that you can get a drop from zones of the tank and count it later in the microscope. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staining

Comment: what's the time frame?

Comment: @comprehensible feed radioactive for [MRI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_resonance_imaging)?

Comment: none of them used mri- [this](http://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-4947842-stock-footage-diatom-algae-movements-under-microscope-magnification-x.html), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xsiYG5bozQ), or [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llO0ZZlSGc8). All they used light microscopy.

Comment: well, using light microscopy I will see in 2d, as I said I need to see them moving in Volume.

Comment: @DanielBay hmm 0.1 cubic metre is pretty large 3d volume.